# Making sure that an appended row is always the last row in a table that is made up of dynamically created rows. .detach()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to append a row that should be the last row of the table. In my code it appears to work the first time a row is added dynamically. But It doesn't become the last row when other rows are added.

I always want the "subtot" row to be the last row but when I append other rows it doesn't change to be the last row. It stays where it is even though other rows are appended.

```
//make sure that subtot is only appended once
  if($('.subtot').length < 1){
     $('<tr class = "subtot"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>test</td></tr>').insertAfter('table     tbody>tr:last');         
}
```

you have to scroll down the **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jack2ky/JWuDV/)** a bit to see the code.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you add new row to the table run following code.

```
 $('table').find('.subtot').detach().appendTo('table');
```

replace 'table' with any selector that identify table element. What it does is it will remove subtot row from table and append it back to the table. By that you can always be sure that subtot is always the last row.

Answer (score 0):

To insert a whole new row, but you have to remember the implicitly inserted `<tbody` element

So how about

```
$('.tableClass > tbody').append('<tr class = "subtot"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>test</td></tr>');
```

to keep it sticky at the bottom, after adding any other rows run

```
$('.tableClass').find('.subtot').detach();
$('.tableClass > tbody').append('<tr class = "subtot"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>test</td></tr>');
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i tried it and it didn't work. it's not that easy the subtot row is not becoming the last row when any other row beside the first row is added.

Comment: Oh - Like a sticky last row.

Comment: $('table >tbody').append('<tr class = "subtot"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>test</td></tr>')  doesn't work there is no class name for the table. I think the problem is that the rows are being put in dynamically and the code doesn't look at the other rows once it is added the first time

Comment: Updated my answer,  BTW you can also always add a class to the table

Comment: thank you for your help. it was helpful. I implemented Ravi's answer and it worked. it is similar to your but he mentioned that i had to insert that detach statement where I add the rows in the code. thank you so much for your help I will close this question soon